# Auto-Refresh Pivot Table with VBA, when Source Table contains Formulas

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, auto-update

My goal is that a `Pivot Table` updates automatically when I make changes to the source data. The "normal" code (see below) discussed here in the forum does not work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("Test").PivotCache.Refresh
End Sub
```

My setup is the following:

- In a tab called "Overview" I have numbers (%) I like to adjust to test different scenarios.
- In tab "Constituents" I have my table (called "Input") which is the basis for my Pivot Table. The numbers in this table change, whenever I make changes to the percentages in tab "Overview" (obviously numbers in table are generated with formulas).
- In tab "Pivot" I have my Pivot Table called "Test".

I have tried my luck with the code stated above. If I overwrite a formula in my table, the Pivot updates automatically. This means that the code works for that scenario.

However: If the numbers in the table change due to the formula (meaning a change in tab "Overview"), my Pivot Table does not update.

Does someone know a way to solve this problem? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to add the Worksheet_Change function in both sheets in "Constituents" as well as in "Overview"

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked when I added the function to the second worksheet.